# Refresh token expiration not updated as expected

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

This is the policy update i made.

```
Set-AzureADPolicy -Id 971c05df-810a-430d-b509-571d61712783 -DisplayName "OrganizationDefaultPolicyScenario" -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"MaxInactiveTime":"14.00:00:00","MaxAgeSingleFactor":"90.00:00:00","MaxAgeMultiFactor":"90.00:00:00"}}')
```

After updating this policy, i tried to generate refresh token using method AcquireTokenByRefreshToken(RefreshToken, clientId).

**Parameters provided for above refresh token generation method:**

**RefreshToken** – Refresh token i got from the method AcquireToken

**Client id** - Client id of corresponding Azure AD

But still i can get refresh token with expiry as 1 hour. Did i miss anything?
Please help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

As I known, ADAL caches refresh token and will automagically use it whenever you call AcquireToken and the requested token need renewing(even you want to get new access token for different resource).

The refresh token in the AuthenticationResults , and corresponding AcquireTokenByRefreshToken method, is one such violation.

You can see more details about this issue in this [article](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/13/adal-3-didnt-return-refresh-tokens-for-5-months-and-nobody-noticed/).

See more details about refresh token in ADAL in this [link](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/09/the-new-token-cache-in-adal-v2/) .